# Software that converts handwriting to computer text

Tags: software, translation

Wondering if anyone had recommendations for software that converts handwriting (fairly legible penmanship) to computerized text? Any hiccups or bottlenecks in the process/workflow? Sensitivity to ink and paper combinations?

A potential project involves the handwritten text on one page and its typewritten conversion on the other. One application is assessing translation quality and integrity from archival texts that are handwritten. Another is for artist's books, ones intended to preserve the aesthetic quality of the author's *calligraphic* style.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with writing. If the software you're looking for has something to do with a writing project, please edit to explain this and we'll consider reopening.

Comment: @NeilFein Ok, I've updated to include a few use-cases.

Comment: calligraphic style isn't on-topic here, but that other use case... I've [asked for another opinion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4996892#4996892) on this.

Comment: Heya mt3, I'm afraid this question has a couple of issues. One is, the fact that these tools _can_ be used for writing, translation, etc., doesn't make them "tools of the trade" unless such use is common practice. [Super User](http://superuser.com) is a good resource for software questions. Secondly, even on SU, general requests for recommendations and lists of viable tools are generally considered unconstructive. See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more info.

Comment: (cont.) So I'm afraid I need to leave this closed. But if you have any new problems that come up during the actual projects, those might be spot-on here!

Comment: Also, here's an old Super User question that might help: http://superuser.com/questions/22157/what-is-a-good-handwriting-recognition-software (via NeilFein).

Answer (score 1):

I've had pretty good luck using the text conversation in Mircosoft OneNote, both scanned in text and hand written stuff, and my handing writing is pretty bad.